# JQ Select Objects Where Inner Key Exists

Tags: json, object, filter, jq

I am trying to select credential objects only if key `credhub-ref` exist within them from the following JSON:

```
{
   "total_results": 23,
   "total_pages": 1,
   "prev_url": null,
   "next_url": null,
   "resources": [
      {
         "entity": {
            "credentials": {},
            "binding_options": {},
            "gateway_data": null,
            "gateway_name": "",
            "syslog_drain_url": null,
            "volume_mounts": [],
            "name": null,
            "last_operation": {
               "type": "create",
               "state": "succeeded",
               "description": "",
               "updated_at": "2018-10-15T19:13:57Z",
               "created_at": "2018-10-15T19:13:57Z"
            },
            "app_url": "/v2/3"
         }
      },
      {
         "entity": {
            "app_guid": "sd",
            "service_instance_guid": "sd",
            "credentials": {
               "hostname": "w",
               "port": 3306
            },
            "binding_options": {},
            "gateway_data": null,
            "gateway_name": "",
            "syslog_drain_url": null,
            "volume_mounts": [],
            "name": null,
            "last_operation": {
               "type": "create",
               "state": "succeeded",
               "description": "",
               "updated_at": "2018-10-15T19:24:06Z",
               "created_at": "2018-10-15T19:24:06Z"
            },
            "app_url": "/v2/3"
         }
      },
      {
         "entity": {
            "credentials": {
               "credhub-ref": "ref3"
            },
            "binding_options": {},
            "gateway_data": null,
            "gateway_name": "",
            "syslog_drain_url": null,
            "volume_mounts": [],
            "name": null,
            "last_operation": {
               "type": "create",
               "state": "succeeded",
               "description": "",
               "updated_at": "2019-03-19T20:07:27Z",
               "created_at": "2019-03-19T20:07:27Z"
            },
            "app_url": "/v2/45"
         }
      },
      {
         "entity": {
            "credentials": {
               "credhub-ref": "ref4"
            },
            "binding_options": {},
            "gateway_data": null,
            "gateway_name": "",
            "syslog_drain_url": null,
            "volume_mounts": [],
            "name": null,
            "last_operation": {
               "type": "create",
               "state": "succeeded",
               "description": "",
               "updated_at": "2019-03-19T20:07:27Z",
               "created_at": "2019-03-19T20:07:27Z"
            },
            "app_url": "/v2/45"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

When I use `cat my_bindings_test2.json |  jq '.resources[] | .entity.credentials'` I get:

```
{}
{
  "hostname": "w",
  "port": 3306
}
{
  "credhub-ref": "ref3"
}
{
  "credhub-ref": "ref4"
}
```

Using JQ, how would I get the following result?

```
{
  "credhub-ref": "ref3"
}
{
  "credhub-ref": "ref4"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is guaranteed that `credhub-ref` won't be `null` or `false`, you can use `select(.["credhub-ref"])`:

```
jq '.resources[].entity.credentials | select(.["credhub-ref"])' file
```

Otherwise refer to @hek2mgl's answer.

Comment: Thanks. New to jq and I was really close several time today.  I was using `jq '.resources[].entity.credentials | select(.credhub-ref)' my_bindings_test.json`

Comment: Welcome. You can use the `.["keyname"]` notation when keyname contains ambiguous characters

Comment: Note: This would not produce output if "credhub-ref" is `null` or `false`. Not sure if that's desired. The correct answer to the question, as it has been asked, would be to use `has("credhub-ref")` - like I showed ;)

Comment: don't forget `false` (edited my comment above and added it)

Comment: np. Well done! PS: `null` and `false` seem to be the only "falsish" values in jq - in opposite to javascript. That's good news! Was never sure about that

Comment: Thanks again. The value should never be false or null, but I’m glad you mentioned this because at I was going to generalize this for future use.

Answer (score 7):

Like this:

```
jq '.resources[].entity.credentials|select(has("credhub-ref"))' file.json
```